# Maven settings.xml file

Tags: xml, maven, settings

What are the elements that go into settings.xml file for maven? Can somebody share a sample file?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html is a great place to start. There is an example and explanation of all the elements.

Answer (score 3):

> The settings element in the settings.xml file contains elements used
>   to define values which configure Maven execution in various ways, like
>   the pom.xmlThese include values such as the local
>   repository location, alternate remote repository servers, and
>   authentication information.

**Below sample has all the required keys with its explanation which might helps in understanding setting xml moe clearly**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<!--
 | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
 |
 |  1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single
 |                 user, and is normally provided in
 |                 ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
 |
 |  2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all
 |                 Maven users on a machine (assuming they're all using the
 |                 same Maven installation). It's normally provided in
 |                 ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
 |
 | The sections in this sample file are intended to give you a running start
 | at getting the most out of your Maven installation. Where appropriate, the
 | default values (values used when the setting is not specified) are provided.
 |
 |-->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ~/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->

  <!-- interactiveMode
   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set
   | to false, maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some
   | other setting, for the parameter in question.
   |
   | Default: true
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  -->

  <!-- offline
   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when
   | executing a build. This will have an effect on artifact downloads,
   | artifact deployment, and others.
   |
   | Default: false
  <offline>false</offline>
  -->

  <!-- pluginGroups
   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when
   | resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e. when invoking a command line like
   | "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not
   | already contained in the list.
   |-->
  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
  </pluginGroups>

  <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to
   | the network. Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-
   | line switch), the first proxy specification in this list marked as active
   | will be used.
   |-->
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>

  <!-- servers
   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used
   | within the system. Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must
   | make a connection to a remote server.
   |-->
  <servers>
    <!-- server
     | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a
     | particular server, identified by a unique name within the system
     | (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
     |
     | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR
     |       privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are used together.
     |
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>repouser</username>
      <password>repopwd</password>
    </server>
    -->

    <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
    <server>
      <id>siteServer</id>
      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
    </server>
    -->
  </servers>

  <!-- mirrors
   | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote
   | repositories.
   |
   | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving
   | certain artifacts. However, this repository may have problems with heavy
   | traffic at times, so people have mirrored it to several places.
   |
   | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a
   | mirror reference for that repository, to be used as an alternate download
   | site. The mirror site will be the preferred server for that repository.
   |-->
  <mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository.
     | The repository that this mirror serves has an ID that matches the
     | mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used for inheritance and direct
     | lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
  </mirrors>

  <!-- profiles
   | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways,
   | and which can modify the build process. Profiles provided in the
   | settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-specific paths and
   | repository locations which allow the build to work in the local
   | environment.
   |
   | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus -
   | that needs to know where your Tomcat instance is installed, you can
   | provide a variable here such that the variable is dereferenced during the
   | build process to configure the cactus plugin.
   |
   | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One
   | way - the activeProfiles section of this document (settings.xml) - will be
   | discussed later. Another way essentially relies on the detection of a
   | system property, either matching a particular value for the property, or
   | merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK
   | version prefix, where a value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the
   | build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'. Finally, the list of
   | active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.
   |
   | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to
   |       specifying only artifact repositories, plugin repositories, and
   |       free-form properties to be used as configuration variables for
   |       plugins in the POM.
   |
   |-->

  <profiles>
    <!-- profile
     | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to be activated
     | using one or more of the mechanisms described above. For inheritance
     | purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/> or the
     | command line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique.
     |
     | An encouraged best practice for profile identification is to use a
     | consistent naming convention for profiles, such as 'env-dev',
     | 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 'user-brett', etc. This
     | will make it more intuitive to understand what the set of introduced
     | profiles is attempting to accomplish, particularly when you only have a
     | list of profile id's for debug.
     |
     | This profile example uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and
     | provides a JDK-specific repo.
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.4</id>

      <activation>
        <jdk>1.4</jdk>
      </activation>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    -->

    <!--
     | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env'
     | with a value of 'dev', which provides a specific path to the Tomcat
     | instance. To use this, your plugin configuration might hypothetically
     | look like:
     |
     | ...
     | <plugin>
     |   <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId>
     |   <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
     |
     |   <configuration>
     |     <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation>
     |   </configuration>
     | </plugin>
     | ...
     |
     | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration whenever someone
     |       set 'target-env' to anything, you could just leave off the
     |       <value/> inside the activation-property.
     |
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>target-env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    -->
  </profiles>

  <!-- activeProfiles
   | List of profiles that are active for all builds.
   |
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  -->
</settings>
```

for any other depth details: may go through http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 3):

As a beginner I feel the above answers are not simple-clear and might confuse the user.

In my opinion the simplest maven settings.xml file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>central</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <mirrorOf>maven_central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Note: the snippet above is a working configuration that will pull wateva plugins one needs, from maven_central.

More info:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

A small joke :)

'for(int i = 0; iAmADumbDude<=infinite.length; i++); { if (please make me smarter with 3 year old examples);{ thank you }; else { bleh } }'

Answer (score 1):

The content depends on the configuration needed for the deployment of the artifacts:

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

But the most important thing is to check what settings are maven taking during the deployment of the artifacts by using this command:

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

Sometimes it can happen that you are using local settings and global settings (taking first the provided by the maven installation and then the provided by the repository). With this command, you can verify the actual settings maven is taking during the deployment. In addition, you can locate the actual file maven is taking and, as a consequence, modify the file properly (with vim, for example) according to the configuration needed by the server.

Remember that there are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

1. Maven installation directory

   $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
2. User-specific settings file

   ~/.m2/settings.xml

> If both files exists, their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being dominant. https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Linux, you can find the default file with comments in /etc/maven/settings.xml